# Pagination with out using buttons in android

Tags: android

How to do Pagination in Android? I have tried with few pagination and most of them use buttons. Is there any separate feature in Android other than using buttons. I need page number in bottom, as how we use to get in our Google page..

Comment: Define "Pagination without buttons"

Comment: Is infinite scroll an option?

Comment: there is no pagination word in android's dictionary.It is called carousal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this example

[ListView Pagination Ex-2](https://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/listview-pagination-ex-2/)

Here the logic is very simple. just add the page numbers dynamically to the footer and load list items based on the number clicked

```
private void Btnfooter()
{
    int val = TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS%NUM_ITEMS_PAGE;
    val = val==0?0:1;
    noOfBtns=TOTAL_LIST_ITEMS/NUM_ITEMS_PAGE+val;

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btnLay);

    btns    =new Button[noOfBtns];

    for(int i=0;i<noOfBtns;i++)
    {
        btns[i] =   new Button(this);
        btns[i].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        btns[i].setText(""+(i+1));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(btns[i], lp);

        final int j = i;
        btns[j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                loadList(j);
                CheckBtnBackGroud(j);
            }
        });
    }

}
```